# vimrcのautoindentが反映されない

Tags: vim

題名通り、.vimrcにあるautoindentが反映されません。
毎回setすることで有効になります
解決策をおねがいします

Comment: 自己解決しました。set pasteをコメントアウトしたところ、正常に反映されました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.vimrc が何らかの理由で読み込まれていないか、他のプラグインで上書きされている可能性があります。

```
:verbose set autoindent?
```

を実行すると最後に設定した箇所が分かります。

Comment: 上記のコマンドを入れてみると、~/.vimrcが示されました。しかしそのファイルではautoindentを有効にするよう設定しており、また他の設定（set numberなど）を変更してみたところ、そちらは反映されていました。